# Highcharts - Format overlapping scatter points in a shared tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a scatter chart in which there are some points in different series which overlap at exact points.
The x,y for both of these points in different series are same.

So I need to show both of them at the same time in tooltip.
However, the `shared` option only works when I'm not formatting the tooltip.

It doesn't work when I use `pointFormat`.
I tried to use `formatter`, but `this` just gives current `point`.
If I switch the chart to line chart, `this` gives `points`, which has all the points in the current position. With that, I can iterate and do the formatting.

**Chart options:**

```
{
    chart: {
        type: 'scatter',
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Height Versus Weight of 507 Individuals by Gender'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Heinz  2003'
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            enabled: true,
            text: 'Height (cm)'
        },
        startOnTick: true,
        endOnTick: true,
        showLastLabel: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Weight (kg)'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 100,
        y: 70,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: Highcharts.defaultOptions.chart.backgroundColor,
        borderWidth: 1
    },          tooltip: {
              formatter: function () {
              console.log(this);
                  return this.points.reduce(function (s, point) {
                      return s + '<br/>' + point.series.name + ': ' +
                          point.point.options.dynamicText;
                  }, '<b>' + this.x + '</b>');
              },
              crosshairs:true,
              shared: true
          },
    plotOptions: {
        scatter: {
            marker: {
                radius: 5,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true,
                        lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                    }
                }
            },
            states: {
                hover: {
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Female',
        color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
        data: [{x:161.2, y:51.6, dynamicText:"foo1"}]

    }, {
        name: 'Male',
        color: 'rgba(119, 152, 191, .5)',
        data: [{x:161.2, y:51.6, dynamicText:"foo2"}]
    }]
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dushyantbangal/ojqde34x/17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared tooltip does not work with `scatter` series - please check this issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/1431

The simplest solution is to use `line` series type with `lineWidth` property set to `0`:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        lineWidth: 0,
        states: {
            hover: {
                lineWidthPlus: 0
            }
        }
    }
},
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3fda1nm4/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.lineWidth

Comment: Haha thats a great hack!